# ruby count for object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

I have a object with the next field:

```
class Post
 field :repost , type: Integer
 attr_accessible :repost
end
```

In my controller in action repost, I want increase the counter + 1.

I try:

```
@post.repost += 1
```

but I get:

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
```

**How can I fix it?.**

Comment: did you try to set a default value to your field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first initialize `repost` with default zero

```
field :repost , type: Integer, :default => 0

@post.repost += 1
```